# Only the default Lumen route is recognized

Tags: php, laravel, docker, lumen

I'm creating routes for my Lumen app and I ran into the following problem.
The default route has the expected return

**web.php**

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
```

the return value:
Lumen (8.2.4) (Laravel Components ^8.0)

but for any URI other than this we have the following error message

500 Internal Server Error nginx

The laravel logs point to the following error

```
local.ERROR: Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable. in /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:1089
Stack trace:
#0 /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(882): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable()
#1 /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(754): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#2 /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(692): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#3 /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(300): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#4 /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/helpers.php(42): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make()
#5 Command line code(1): app()
#6 {main}
  thrown {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Uncaught Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\\Contracts\\Http\\Kernel] is not instantiable. in /home/wesleytio/laravelProjects/russian-catholica/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:1089
Stack trace:
#0 .../vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(882): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->notInstantiable()
#1 .../vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(754): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 .../vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(692): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 .../vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(300): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#4 .../vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/helpers.php(42): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->make()
#5 Command line code(1): app()
#6 {main}
  thrown at /.../vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:1089)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be done?

Comment: Can we see how you define the other routes and what version of php do you run this on?

Comment: Nginx error would indicate something is wrong with your nginx config - you maybe wanna s sahre it as well?